# How can you ignore a universal link if a certain condition is not met?

Tags: ios, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

We currently support wildcarding for Universal Links. So my applinks looks like: `applinks:*.company.com`.

Let's say I want to only handle a link if it is `https://company.com/?query1=abc`

Let's say I instead tap on a link that is `https://company.com/?query1=123`

Since the condition is not met, I want to ignore this link and prevent my iOS App from responding to it. Is this possible?

I thought I'd just be able to return `false` in [continue:restorationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application) but that does not prevent the iOS App from opening.

Comment: If your app can't handle the URL it has to call `open` on the URL to return the user back to safari.  Universal links opened *by* your app will never be opened *in* your app.  The user will still see your app open followed by a bounce back to Safari.

Comment: @Paulw11 nice recommendation. I assumed this would have led to a recursive call for some reason but looks like it doesn't. Want to submit it as the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `false` from `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` doesn't result in the URL being passed back to Safari (as you have discovered). The documentation states:

> If you don't implement this method or if your implementation returns false, iOS tries to create a document for your app to open using a URL

So returning false just results in iOS trying to launch your app in a different way.

What you can do is call [`open(_:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) and pass the URL you received.  The URL will then be opened in Safari; iOS won't pass your app a universal link that your app opens itself because that could create an infinite loop.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that the app is safe to `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` the link again and it doesn't cause any recursion? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: If your app calls `open` then the link will be opened in safari no matter what the site association file contains. The logic is that if the app is calling `open` then it is unable to handle the link. If the app is able to handle the link,it wouldn't call `open` on it.